# How do I find all the restaurants in a city without mentioning radius

Tags: python, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I am looking for all the restaurants in 10 cities. Some are small in area and some are bigger. I can't specify the radius. For example, consider the location name Chandigarh. I have picked up lat longs of the center of Chandigarh `'30.740889611128623, 76.77223250477658'`. Now I want to find all the restaurants in Chandigarh. If specified radius it will be not valid for the cities. I want to find restaurants based on location, not City. Thus I can't dynamic my code. How do I achieve it? This below given error `ApiError: INVALID_REQUEST`.

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)
places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(location='30.740889611128623, 76.77223250477658', name='Chandigarh', open_now =False , type = 'restaurant')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Places API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place):

> **INVALID_REQUEST** indicates the API request was malformed, generally due
> to the missing required query parameter (location or radius).

Indeed, in your code you specify the location parameter, but you don't provide a radius parameter. You can omit a radius parameter only if you
specify rankby=distance in your request.

**radius** — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that radius must not be included if rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is specified.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) on Nearby search.

Comment: `places_result  = places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(location='30.740889611128623, 76.77223250477658',rankby='distance', name='Chandigarh', open_now =False , type = 'restaurant')`. It says "places_nearby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rankby'"

Comment: It seems the [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427079/google-places-api-rankby-location-problems) is slightly wrong.This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358364/google-places-api-rankby-distance-not-working) might be helpful to you let me know if it doesn’t help.